# Showing two improper integrals converge

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In the last excercise of one of my college practice sheets, we are requested to determine whether the integrals

$$a)\int_1 ^\infty \frac{e^x}{x^x}dx, \space \space b) \int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x \ln^x(x)}dx$$

converge or diverge. Generally, the last excercises in the sheet are the hardest ones. I found this problem extremely easy (solved in one line basically), which makes me suspicious of my approach. Am I doing something wrong? What I did follows.

$a)$ $\sqrt[n]{|\frac{e^n}{n^n}|}=\frac{e}{n} \rightarrow0<1$ shows the series convergence absolutely. Thus, due to the integral test for convergence, the integral converges.

$b)$. Same logic, simply notice that

$$\sqrt[n]{|\frac{1}{n \ln^n(n)}|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}\ln n} \rightarrow0<1$$

and the series converges absolutely. Therefore, the integral converges.

Am I missing something? Or is this procedure correct? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It seems fine, as the functions are decreasing eventually. For the first integral you can as well apply the comparison test, as for $x\ge e^2$ we have ${e^x\over x^x}\le {e^x\over e^{2x}}=e^{-x}.$ Concerning the second integral for $x\ge e$ we have ${1\over x\log^xx}\le {1\over x\log^2x}.$ The antiderivative in this case is equal $-{1\over \log x}.$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning is sound, although to be totally rigorous, you also need to establish that the integrands are monotone decreasing, as this is a requirement for the integral test for convergence.

To see why, can you think of a counterexample; i.e., a function $f(x) > 0$ that is not monotone decreasing, such that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) < \infty$$ but $$\int_{x=1}^\infty f(x) \, dx = \infty?$$

Comment: Makes total sense. Thank you so much!